# Do these multimeter readings even make sense?

Tags: multimeter

[image]I'm measuring resistor values and I believe I've set the multimeter correctly. I verified some pre-known values.

Measuring this one resistor, I get 3.0 on the 200M scale and 0.03 on the 20M scale and no reading on the 200K scale.

Does it make sense?

I assume 0.03 on the 20M scale - means 30k Ohms. Then shouldn't I be able to read 30 on the 200K scale.

I'm new to electronics.

Comment: This is an analog meter, I assume? Because digital meters (every digital meter I have seen anyways) will show you the units regardless of what scale you are in rather than showing you a number which you will have to manually scale based on the range. If it is an analog meter, edit your post and add a photo of the readout scale.

Comment: Is the battery ok?  Did you verify 0 Ohms on each range?

Comment: It's a digital unit - but I don't see any units. I opened the unit and it's a 9V battery. Of course with the battery out of the mm - I can't test the voltage - drats! Will replace it tommorow. Yes I read 0 ohms when the probes are not connected.

Comment: @dashman Some people..some.. might suggest licking the battery terminals as a test. A good jolt indicates it's okay for a multimeter. Are your sure about those ranges? A 200M range is unusually high. A photo of the meter face and the resistor would help. A 3K resistor would read 3.0 on the 200K range (assuming 3-1/2 digits) and 0.003 or .003 on the 2M range (and overrange on the 2K range).

Comment: What brand/model is the multimeter?

Comment: The brand is ETEKCITY - cheapie. The resistor was attached to a micro low power motor w/ 1.5 AA battery. To measure the resistance I freed one end of the resistor from the circuit and removed battery. It's a black/gray resistor with no color bands.

Comment: Are you certain that it is a resistor you're measuring? Could it be a diode? Try measuring with probes switched (measure in both directions)...if you get a different reading, it is likely a diode. Also, ensure your fingers don't touch the metal probe tips while measuring.

Comment: I switched probes at 200M and got different readings. Switched probes at 20M got the same 0.03 reading. So that's 30k Ohms right? But then on the next lower range 200k - it reads 0L.

Comment: Try it on a known resistor.  Maybe post a picture of the meter as you have it set up for the measurement -- you could be doing something wrong without realizing, and 1000 words and all that.

Comment: Added image to op. The black probe end goes to the + of 1.5 battery - I took the battery out - so not connected to circuit. At 20M range - getting 0.03/0.04 on both probe switches. On 200K, I'm getting 11.9 and when I switch probe get 0L.

Comment: It's a little hard to see in the image, but I think it's a diode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Measuring this one resistor

The photo shows that you are **not** measuring a resistor - it looks like a diode (as commented by *glen_geek*). The photo shows the grey band (cathode) end connected to the red lead from the DMM.

Trying to measure a diode on different resistance ranges explains the different readings (due to the different test currents used) and explains why the meter shows "OL" when the leads are swapped.

Also, just to be clear, you must not have power source (e.g. the 1.5V battery you mentioned that you had removed temporarily) in the circuit when performing anything other than a current or voltage measurement (so not when performing resistance test, or diode test, or capacitance test (on suitable meters) etc.).

Use the diode test on the meter to test the diode, if that is what you want to do.

(Posting from mobile - please excuse any typos etc.)

Comment: Thanks. Apologies for this very basic question...as I wrote just starting out.